# Ploting a simple binaryThresholding function graph in matlab as shown in image and figure

Tags: matlab, plot, graph

How can I correct this code, I have been trying to do it from 2 day but unable to do it still. Please help.

function BinaryThresholding(I)

```
%Reading minimum and maximum intensity values of Image I.
Min = min(I(:));
Max = max(I(:));
%Finding the middle value (thresholding) A.K.A m below.
m = (Min+Max)/2;


%For ploting the thresholding tranformation function we will also
%define X and Y (Ranges) parameters based upon min and max range and the
%process them according to our transformation algoritm as below.



 x = (Min/Max):(Max/Max);   %input range. 
 y = x;

% Now we will apply alogithm to threshold the threshold I at
% the middle intensity,thresholdingValue, of its dynamic 
% range [minValue maxValue]. G is our processed image.
[Rows, Columns, Channels] = size(I);

%First we will check if the image is gray-scale and conver it if not.
if(Channels==3)
I = rgb2gray(I);
end
%Processing Image.
for i=1:1:Rows
    for j=1:1:Columns
        if( I(i,j)< m)
            G(i,j) = 0;
        else
            G(i,j) = 1;
        end
    end
end
% Algorithm works great :D --> Testingw with : figure, imshow(G);

%Displaying image on a new figure window.
figure('Name','Image Thresholding','NumberTitle','on'),
   subplot(1,3,1); imshow(I); title(['Input Image - Dynamic Range: [',num2str(Min),' ',num2str(Max),']']);
   subplot(1,3,2); imshow(G); title(['Output Image - Threshold:' num2str(m)]);
   subplot(1,3,3); plot(x,y); title('Plot of Thresholding Transformation Function');
%Let pixel info to be shown on the figure.
impixelinfo;
%Writing the image G as a .png file to the current folder (Drive D:/).
```

%     imwrite(G,'D:/G.png');

end[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zsc1.jpg)

[Actual output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3iLi.jpg)

Comment: `y=x` so it's normal that you have a diagonal line. instead do `y(x<m) = 0; y(x>=m) = 1;`.  You should also get rid of the loops: `G=I; G(I<m) = 0; G(I>=m) = 1;`  Also take in account that if your image is completely black, then Max will be 0 so `x` will have incorrect values since (Min/0 = Inf)

Comment: also in `imwrite` the path D: looks like you are using a Windows system, so you should use backslash \ so separate folders instead of a slash / used in linux systems.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I was writing an answer on my own, but it looks like you were faster, I didn't want to copy :)

Comment: Don't worry, actually the code needs a lot of refactoring, so I just pointed couple of things in a comment.

Comment: imwrite is working well cuz it save the transformed image as i want it to

Comment: G is the output Image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the title of outputs I think you want to fix this line

```
   subplot(1,3,3); plot(x,y); title('Plot of Thresholding Transformation Function');
```

which means only correct these couple of lines

```
x = (Min/Max):(Max/Max);   %input range. 
y = x;
```

that means: x is equally spaced from min to max... and **Y is also equally spaced** from min to max (as you can see from your actual output). Try something like:

```
x = (Min/Max):(Max/Max);   %input range. 
y = zeros(length(x));
for i=1:length(x)
 if (x > m)
  y(i) = 1;
 end
end
```

Comment: let me check it :)